# Editing netcat output before writing to txt file

Tags: linux, shell, netcat

I am trying to edit the output of netcat before writing it to a txt file.

The following command does not seem to work:

```
nc -l 1240 | cut -d “;” -f 1 > textfile.txt
```

when i break it into two parts it works fine eg

```
nc -l 1240 | -d “;” -f 1
```

works, and

```
nc -l 1240 2>&1 > textfile.txt
```

works fine too

but when i string them together it does not work.
any thoughts appreciated
thanks

Comment: Works perfectly for me (if I replace your weird non-programmery quotes with normal double-quotes, `-d ";"`). Can you define "does not work"? Do you get an error? Is the file created? What is its content?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nc -l 1240 &>&1 | cut -d ";" -f1 > textfile.txt
```